# Handling POST arrays in Symfony 4 in security.yaml

Tags: symfony, yaml, symfony4

I have the following form:

```
<form name="user_login" method="post">
<div id="user_login">
    <div>
        <label for="user_login_email" class="required">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="user_login_email"
               name="user_login[email]"
               required="required">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="user_login_password" class="required">Password</label>
        <input type="password"
               id="user_login_password"
               name="user_login[password]"
               required="required">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" id="user_login_save" name="user_login[save]">
            Log in
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My question is how can I get the login parameters in the security.yaml file?

The part of my security.yaml file resposible for this looks like this now:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                username_parameter: "user_login[email]"
                password_parameter: "user_login[password]"
```

I've tried some variations such as using single quotes, using a dot to reference the key etc, but none of them seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The username and password parameters are corrects.

The problem is your form, specifically the action url. It should be the login check page.

```
<form name="user_login" method="post" action="/login_check">
```

Comment: Hello, I've got my check_path and login_path configured to be user_sign_in the security.yaml file. I just didn't find it necessary to share it for this particular problem. The code is generated via
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
I've tried with action attribute, but the result is the same.

Comment: Try something like this: `{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('user_sign_in')}) }}`

Comment: As I said, I've tried with the **action** attribute in the form, the result is the same. I think this has to do with the security.yaml file.

Comment: Can you post your complete `security.yaml` ?

Comment: You're using the same route for the login and the login_check. The check_path has to have its own route.

Comment: When I use simple strings such as **_name** and **_password** as input names, everything works fine. I believe the problem is elsewhere.